# NullpointerException when mocking dao method

Tags: java, junit, mockito, jmockit

I started writing testclass for my Java-Spring-project. I use JUnit and Mockito
But no matter I do, I always get a NullpointerException, for the below statement.

```
assert((dao.getAllBusinessRules(sourceSystemIdentifier)).size()>=0);
```

Here's my main class

```
Public class   BusinessRulesDao   extends   SimpleDaoImpl‹BusinessRules>
{
static  f1naI    String   GET_BUSINESS_RULES=“se1ect className, fileName , sourceSystemldentifier from Business_Rules where sourceSystemIdentifier=?”;

public List<BusinessRules> getAllBusinessRules(String sourceSystemIdentifier) {
SQLParameter param = new SQLParameter(Types.VARCHAR, "sourcesystemldentifier", sourceSystemtIdentifier);
List<BusinessRules› list = null;
ArrayList<IDBParameter> params = new ArrayList<IDBParameter›();
params.add(param) ;
1ist = this.query(GET_BUSINESS_RULES, params);
return list;
}
```

Here's my testclass

```
public  class BusinessRulesDaoTest {
@Before
public void initMocks() {
MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}

BusinessRulesDao dao =Mockito.mock(BusinessRulesDao.class);
@Mock
BusinessRules rules;
SimpleDaoImpl<BusinessRules> impl=Mockito.mock(SimpleDaoImpl.class);

@Before
Public void setUp()
{
    this.rules=new BusinessRules();
    this.dao =new BusinessRulesDao();
    assert(this.dao!=null&&this.rules!=null);
}
@Test
Public void getAllBusinessRulesTest()
{
String sourceSystemIdentifier=”ssi”;
String sql=”sql”;
ArrayList<IDBParameter> params=new ArrayList<IDBParameter>();
List<BusinessRules> list = new ArrayList<>();
When(dao.getAllBusinessRules(anyString()).thenReturn(list);
When(impl.query(sql,params)).thenReturn(list);
list.add(rules);
assert((dao.getAllBusinessRules(sourceSystemIdentifier)).size()>=0);
}
}
```

Comment: Here's your problem - `this.impl=new SimpleDaoImpl< BusinessRules>();` It _was_ a mock till you did this to it!

Comment: I tried commenting this. But the test won't go into the main method and I can see zero coverage after test.

Comment: Well, are you trying to mock this class or not?  If this is the class you're testing, then you shouldn't mock it at all.  But if you're testing some other class that interacts with it, then a mock may be exactly what you need.

Comment: I just want to test BusinessRulesDao class only and need to get 100% coverage also. I tried to test with commenting this.impl=new SimpleDaoImpl< BusinessRules>(); Now I'm getting nullpointer exception in assert((dao.getAllBusinessRules(sourceSystemIdentifier)).size()>=0);
.

Comment: this is not jmockit